# Where Enterprise Library Configuration Editor for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, enterprise-library

Where Enterprise Library Configuration Editor for Visual Studio 2015?
Is this feature missing for Visual Studio 2015?
I'm on EL5.

Comment: Possbile duplicate of [Does Enterprise Library 6 work with Visual Studio 2013 and/or 2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309323/does-enterprise-library-6-work-with-visual-studio-2013-and-or-2015)

Answer (score 1):

EntperiseLibrary.Config V6 extension is not supporting Visual Studio 2015. So you need to update the config file to add the support.

You can find a compatible version for VS 2015 [here](https://randylevy.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/enterpriselibrary-config-for-vs2015/)

It worked for me.