# This extension is not installable on any currently installed products

Tags: c#

I have Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.50727 when I wanted to install XNA Game Studio 4.0.vsix.
 I have an error that log error is :

> Extension Details...
>
> Identifier      : bcc70cc4-703d-4f8b-98f5-d96bfc71335b
>
> Name            : XNA Game Studio 4.0
>
> Version         : 1.4.12
>
> Description     : XNA Game Studio Package provides game development
>   experiences for Xbox 360, Windows, and Windows Phone.
>
> SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : 4.5
>
> VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not
>   installable on any currently installed products.  at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

How can I fixed it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215916/vsixinstaller-noapplicableskusexception-this-extension-is-not-installable-on-an) help?  or maybe [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309323/does-enterprise-library-6-work-with-visual-studio-2013-and-or-2015)

Comment: AFAIK the last Visual Studio version that supported XNA was 2010