# VSIX Installer extension is not installable on any current installed products

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installation, visual-studio-2017, vsix

I tried to install objc-syntax-highlighting.vsix in visual studio 2017 community offline. I could not resolve it. I've downloaded extension package from https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/releases and tried to install package from 0.2 Preview (December 2017)

```
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - -------------------------------------------
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - 15.5.99+g87f89a485e
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - -------------------------------------------
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - Command line parameters:
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa10400.20842\objc-syntax-highlighting.vsix
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - -------------------------------------------
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2/21/2018 11:58:55 AM - -------------------------------------------
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - Initializing Install...
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - Extension Details...
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     Identifier         : VSIX..9c35fff1-f084-44c1-a38e-68c707163aa2
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     Name               : Objective-C Language Service
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     Author             : Microsoft
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     Version            : 1.5
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     Description        : This package contains Objective-C language service components such as syntax higlighting etc
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     Locale             : en-US
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     MoreInfoURL        : 
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - 
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     SignatureState     : Unsigned
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     Supported Products : 
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -             Version : [12.0,15.0)
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -             Version : [12.0,15.0)
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -             Version : [12.0,15.0)
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -             Version : [12.0,15.0)
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -             Version : [12.0,15.0)
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - 
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     References         : 
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - Signature Details...
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM -     Extension is not signed.
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - 
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - Searching for applicable products...
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2017
2/21/2018 11:58:58 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
at VSIXInstaller.App.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, Boolean isRepairSupported, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Could anyone help me out this?

Comment: install the objc-language-services-VS2017.vsix

Comment: have you tried the objc-language-services-VS2017.vsix?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry for very delay reply, it works fine. Thanks for the answer

Comment: ok, I've posted it as answer so that you can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Related post - [VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41215916/465053)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the wrong extension. For Visual Studio 2017 install the `objc-language-services-VS2017.vsix` which supports VS2015 and Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the log file you have included, you have VS2017 Community installed on your computer and we can see this confirmed in the latter part of the log file. From the middle of the log we can see that this extension is supported on VS2012 & VS2015 community/ultimate/premium/professional/enterprise. Hence you get the error message:

> This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

The solution is to simply download the version of extension for VS2017 Community.

However if this does not solve it, [there is a solution to a similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24348026/6075112).

The gist of the solution above is this:

- It turns out that the `.vsix` extension is just a `.zip` file.
- Rename the extension from `.vsix` to `.zip`
- Locate the file called `extension.vsixmanifest` in the folder and open it in a text editor like notepad.
- Use `Ctrl + F` to find the `Supported Products` section.
- Add the following:

```xml
    <VisualStudio Version="15.0"> <!-- VS2017 -->
       <Edition>Community</Edition>
       <Edition>Ultimate</Edition>
       <Edition>Premium</Edition>
       <Edition>Pro</Edition>
    </VisualStudio>
```

- Save and close the file.
- Rename the extension from `.zip` back to `.vsix`
- Double click to run.

Comment: Great solution +1. I just figured I'd add that in the case of the .vsix I had to edit, the entries were in the <Installation> section and followed formats like <InstallationTarget Version="10.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate" /> I confirmed that this syntax led to a successful installation

Answer (score 1):

The package can only be installed in VS 2015 and earlier, ask the author for an update